# Hide/show elements depending on view when scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, show-hide

Sounds like a simple waypoint.js and animate.js issue, but its a bit different. I am using 'isScrolledIntoView' elements, but the problem is that multiple elements are viewable at once on the page. Ideally I would like the first element to show until the next element is entirely viewable so that only one element is present at a time. Right now I am having the issue of more than one element showing at the same time, which makes for a not so nice presentation. Here is what I have tried, and here is the website I have tried it on.

The floating ball shows different elements dependent on the scroll position. I'm sure you will be able to see the issue in this example.

http://www.omnihustle.com

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom >= docViewTop) && (elemTop <= docViewBottom));
}

var myelement = $('#home-screen'); // the element to act on if viewable
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if(isScrolledIntoView(myelement)) {
        $(".coupontooltip").show("slow");


    } else {
    $(".coupontooltip").hide("slow");            

    }
});
});

</script>



<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom >= docViewTop) && (elemTop <= docViewBottom));
}

var myelement = $('#services'); // the element to act on if viewable
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if(isScrolledIntoView(myelement)) {
          $(".coupontooltip2").show("slow");




    } else {
        $(".coupontooltip2").hide("slow");

    }
});
});

</script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom >= docViewTop) && (elemTop <= docViewBottom));
}

var myelement = $('#agents'); // the element to act on if viewable
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if(isScrolledIntoView(myelement)) {
            $(".coupontooltip3").show("slow");



    } else {
        $(".coupontooltip3").hide("slow");
    }
});
});

</script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom >= docViewTop) && (elemTop <= docViewBottom));
}

var myelement = $('#portal'); // the element to act on if viewable
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if(isScrolledIntoView(myelement)) {
            $(".coupontooltip4").show("slow");



    } else {
        $(".coupontooltip4").hide("slow");
    }
});
});

</script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom >= docViewTop) && (elemTop <= docViewBottom));
}

var myelement = $('#webdesign'); // the element to act on if viewable
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if(isScrolledIntoView(myelement)) {
            $(".coupontooltip5").show("slow");



    } else {
        $(".coupontooltip5").hide("slow");
    }
});
});

</script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom >= docViewTop) && (elemTop <= docViewBottom));
}

var myelement = $('#social'); // the element to act on if viewable
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if(isScrolledIntoView(myelement)) {
            $(".coupontooltip6").show("slow");



    } else {
        $(".coupontooltip6").hide("slow");
    }
});
});

</script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom >= docViewTop) && (elemTop <= docViewBottom));
}

var myelement = $('#pvf'); // the element to act on if viewable
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if(isScrolledIntoView(myelement)) {
            $(".coupontooltip7").show("slow");



    } else {
        $(".coupontooltip7").hide("slow");
    }
});
});

</script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom >= docViewTop) && (elemTop <= docViewBottom));
}

var myelement = $('#pricing'); // the element to act on if viewable
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if(isScrolledIntoView(myelement)) {
            $(".coupontooltip8").show("slow");



    } else {
        $(".coupontooltip8").hide("slow");
    }
});
});

</script>
```

Comment: Why are you declaring same function multiple times. Also you should declare that function in global scope, so move it outside document ready handler.

Comment: This is what I have come up with to make it work the way it is working now. It seems that what needs to be added to this code is to hide the not "in view" elements when the new element is viewable. If there is another solution, I am here to learn about it.

Comment: Solved: Just added an id to whatever element was far enough off of the screen to not show multiple elements at once.